# Jekyll theme with list of pages?

Tags: themes, jekyll, github-pages

I'd like to have list of the **pages** (not posts) on my Jekyll site.

I found code examples which can be added to the theme to get the pages; that works. But I'm not a good designer to fit the list nicely into the existing theme.

Is there an existing Jekyll theme which allows to see the pages of the site in some convenient way?

The site is hosted on `github-pages`, if that matters.

Comment: Can you provide links to the code examples and/or the code examples themselves, as well as the theme? Without that, it's hard for us to understand what you mean by "fit the list nicely into the existing theme"

Answer (score 0):

I use **[Minimal Mistakes](https://mademistakes.com/work/minimal-mistakes-jekyll-theme/)** which has everything you need and works great on `github-pages`.

Here is my first attempt with it: **[scala-adapters](https://pme123.github.io/scala-adapters/)**